# How to create a Macro that runs only on selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

OK, So I have a very specific problem that I hope to make not-a-problem, but I need some help. I am a complete neophyte when it comes to making Macros.

I’ve got a customer that has put long lists of references in a single column in Excel (normally, the references are just in one cell). I’ve figured out how to consolidate a selected portion of a column of references into a single cell (see my procedure below), but what I’d really like to do is to turn this into a Macro that does it instantly.

The problem is that I’d like to be able to run a Macro on a selection, that is, I’d like to select the cells and have the macro run on ONLY those cells. Then I could select the cells, run the macro, make another selection, run the macro, etc. This would speed up my work tremendously.

My problem: **I can’t figure out how to make the Macro run on just a selection**. The Macros I’ve recorded only run on the selections I’ve made while recording the Macro. Is there any way to make the Macro generic, so I can select cells, and then run the Macro on them?

Combining References in Excel

1. Let’s say the references you want to combine are in E18:E27
2. Make a new column next to the reference designator column, for consolidated references
3. In a blank cell in the new column, where you want to combine all the values, type:
4. =CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(
5. Then select the cells that need to be combined
6. The formula will change to =CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(E18:E27
7. Don’t press enter yet.
8. Click after the last cell reference and hit spacebar
9. Type the & operator
10. Type ”, ” (double quote, comma, space, double quote)
11. This will add a comma and a space after every reference
12. Select TRANSPOSE(E18:E27 &", " and press the F9 key (F9 replaces formulas with values)
13. This replaces TRANSPOSE(E18:E27 &" " with its result, {"E18, ","E19, ","E20, ","E21, ","E22, ","E23, ","E24, ","E25, ","E26, ","E27, "}
14. Now remove the curly brackets { and }
15. The formula will now look like =CONCATENATE("E18, ","E19, ","E20, ","E21, ","E22, ","E23, ","E24, ","E25, ","E26, ","E27, "
16. Select the entire formula, including the = sign, and hit F9
17. Hit Enter
18. Done!

Note: this only works for up to 256 references. Any more and the formula will thrown an error. **If there's any way to change it so it will work on more than that, please let me know**.

**Here's the code I get just by Record Macro-ing the procedure above, with "relative references" turned on. I don't know if that will help me or not.**

```
Sub ConsolidateReferencesMacro2()
'
' ConsolidateReferencesMacro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "U102, U103, U104, U105, U199, U200, U201, U202, U204, U205, U206, 
U207, U232, U233, U234, U235, U245, U246, U44, U45, U65, U66, "
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=128).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I don't see "Concactencate" and "Transpose" so I don't know what is actually happening in this bit of code.

Comment: Would probably be easier to break the code down a bit. Might be an idea to assign your range to a variable like `MyRange = “E18:E27”`. Then make a loop, `For each c in Range(MyRange).Cells`.

Comment: If you’re selecting the area yourself, then you could use `MyRange = Selection`.

Comment: I think you should post the code you've recorded. It's possible that it can be tweaked by replacing the hardcoded range address in the recording with some range variable (e.g. `rangeToConsolidate`), then `Set rangeToConsolidate =  Selection` (assuming you've highlighted/selected some cells). You could assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut, which should then reduce the procedure to 1. highlight/select cells, 2. press keyboard shortcut to execute macro. But start by posting the recorded code.

Comment: OK, I have added the code from recording my procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste following code in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub concat_result()
Selection(Selection.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1) = concat_select(Selection)
End Sub

Function concat_select(R1 As Range) As String
concat_select = Join(Application.Transpose(R1.Value2), ",")
End Function
```

Then you can either call the function `concat_select` as a standard worksheet function or use the `concat_result` sub after selecting your range via a button or shortcut.

Comment: Oh!!!! That works =D THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! This has been a problem for me for years and I can't explain my feelings right now xD I'm in AWE that such a simple code does pretty much exactly what I want :) 

The only thing I'd change is the result of the macro outputs at the bottom of the adjacent column, I'd prefer if it would output at the top, that is to say, if the column is A15 to A20, then the results would be at B15. I don't even know if that's possible to do! 

And again, so many, many, many thanks!!

Comment: To put the result next to the first selected cell, just replace `Selection(Selection.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1)` by `Selection(1, 1).Offset(0, 1)`

Comment: That is perfection itself! Again, thank you very, very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not 100% sure if I understand everything correctly, but as mentioned in my comments, it seems as if you could take advantage of using loops.

As I can see you’re new to the VBA-game.
I therefore explain some things to you, dom’t know if you already know some terms..

Looping in Excel can be used for ranges, for great results. This will let you be able to look in each cell, and determine a value, format or whatever you want, based on this cell.

You told me your range was in a selection, and that you want to make your code beside it.

Your code could therefore be something like:

```
Sub ConsolidateValues()
Dim c As Range

MyRange = Application.Selection.Address(False, False, xlA1)
FrstC = Left(MyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(":", MyRange) - 1)
CVal = ""

For Each c In Selection

CValue = c
CVal = CVal & CValue & ", "

Next c

Range(FrstC).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
FrstCOff = Range(FrstC).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
Range(FrstCOff).Value = CVal

End Sub
```

This should consolidate your Range into one cell to the right of “E17”.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

Sadly, I pasted your code in but upon attempting to use it, Excel told me it had a "Compile Error: Syntax Error"

"Sub ConsolidateValues()" was highlighted.

Comment: "Sub ConsolidateValues()" was highlighted.

Comment: Sorry, I made something wrong… Look at it again, I have just edited the code :)

Comment: Note that it would probably be easier for you to not select the data. You can make excel select the data for you. Might be easier and more efficient on the long run, since you need to select the data here :)

Comment: It would be even nicer if I could just select the column and then let the Macro consolidate each section of references. That sounds like a much greater complication for coding though. My problem is a specific customer that has their Bill of Materials badly formatted. Each list of references should be in a single cell (separated by a comma), but they are instead singly listed in a column of cells. This wouldn't be such a pain except there are some assemblies with thousands of references. 

Anyway, I appreciate your help, but user O.PAL whipped up something simple that works.

Comment: I see.. No matter what you have two different types of codes for your solution. I don't think that it would be to hard to make VBA select the data for you. You just need something for it to search for :)